# Plural of axis mundi

Tags: grammar-choice, plural

The phrase axis mundi is used frequently in archaeology and art history to describe certain places as a "world center" or "center of the universe" in Indigenous or ancient/historical thought. How would this phrase be correctly pluralized? For instance, "By the early first millennium BCE, new urban centers developed across the region and were conceptualized as *axes*(?) *mundi*(?)." Any insight would be useful!

Comment: Is the *axis mundi* the center of the world, or is it **that which everything else revolves around**?

Comment: @RonJohn That'd make a nice separate question! The exact meaning of the phrase and also *axis* in itself is worth exploring properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the nominative plural of *axis* is [*axes*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/axis#Latin).

*Mundi* 'of the world' is the genitive singular of [*mundus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mundus#Etymology_2) 'world', and you probably wouldn't pluralize it in most contexts (presumably there's still only one world), but should it become necessary to do so, the genitive plural is *mundorum* 'of the worlds'.

*Axes mundi* reads correctly to me, for your purposes.

Comment: *Axis mundi*, "centre of [a/the/one] world"; *axes mundi*, "centres of the world"; *axes mundorum* "centres of [some/the/multiple] worlds"; and for completeness, *axis mundorum* "centre of the worlds". Is that correct?

Comment: @TimPederick *Axis* means axis/axle, not centre, but otherwise yes.

Comment: @Cairnarvon the axle is in the center of the wheel.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: I was just using OP's phrasing.

Comment: @RonJohn The nose is in the centre of the face and you'd still be wrong to translate *nasus* as centre.

Comment: @Cairnarvon my point is that people have been interpreting *axis* as *center* for a long time.

Comment: Honestly, I do not see how one world can have more than one axis, whether in a literal or a metaphorical sense.

Comment: @fdb: In the Cartesian sense, the Earth has three. (At least.)